# How to change from Random placement of turtles to fixed placement

Tags: netlogo

Grasses (green leaf) are randomly placed across the world with setxy random-xcor random-ycor. What I want is for its position to be fixed (e.g., every leaf will be placed 10 units apart per line). Can anyone helped me how to alter my setxy, or is there any other way. Thank you very much

[image: Grasses (green leaf) are randomly placed across the world with setxy random-xcor random-ycor]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the `mod` modulus operator will do the trick for you. For example:

```
to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 50 0 50
  ask patches with [ pxcor mod 10 = 0 and pycor mod 10 = 0 ] [
    sprout 1 [
      set shape "leaf"
      set color green
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```